# There is some way to ignore the css style on copy?

Tags: css, copy-paste

Example:

```
<p style="color:blue; font-family:Consolas">blue text</p>
```

The user select the text, copy and paste (wysiwyg, word, etc). And the text comes without blue color and consolas font?

From browser to browser = simple content to wysiwyg

From browser to word

There's a manual with keywords that can be used on content.
The users usually copy the keywords directly from manual and paste in the editor. So the editor assumes the style of the manual. And that's what I don't want.
I can disable the select or change the tags of keywords to input and style it, but exists a easy way?

Comment: From what program to what program?

Comment: @JonasG.Drange: Probably from a rich text editor (Microsoft Word, Open/Libre Office Writer) to a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: The copy/paste behavior would depend on the application you are copying from and the application you are pasting to.

Comment: There should be a "raw paste"/"paste without formatting" option in your target program. Otherwise, you can use Notepad as a proxy.

Comment: Do you want **your** browser to behave like that or shall all your website users be able to copy without styles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to allow users to copy text from a website, and the text be unformatted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331422/is-there-a-way-to-allow-users-to-copy-text-from-a-website-and-the-text-be-unfor)

Answer (score 1):

This is a native OS/software feature. This is not something you can control via js/html.

You can however build a function via javascript that copies that text to clipboard.

Or search for the native feature in your options to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

This is default in all the windows operating systems. when ever you select the text the blue color will occur in select area. manually we never change the color. i think this answer very usefull to you.....

Comment: We can easily disable the text selection using css property and that's why I thought it was the same with the style.

`{user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none;}`