# Is there any way to prevent copy content of html div or input text with its style to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Example:

```
<div id="184" style="position: relative;" class="EditBox" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true">SomeText</div>
```

What I want to achieve is when the user copy the text, prevent copying its style.
Is there a way using DOM or javascript or anything possible to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is some way to ignore the css style on copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802083/there-is-some-way-to-ignore-the-css-style-on-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding an event listener to the div or input, which intercepts the copy command and instead it copies the plain text instead of the html style:

```
document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
alert('Copied');
   e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello! Welcome');
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

use innerText and textContent to get copy the text

```
let text = document.getElementById("184").innerText || document.getElementById("184").textContent;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value =  document.getElementById("184").innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

```css
.EditBox{
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="184" style="position: relative;" class="EditBox" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true">SomeText</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad but what I needed not just get the text but a full interaction with the clipboard, that was the issue, I needed to prevent the html style from being applied to the text of clipboard, so simply plain text instead.